# Compile Statically Linked GO Executable for use in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, compilation, static-linking

**Context:** I am trying to compile a *Go* program (Specifically, the [go-sigma-rule-engine](https://github.com/markuskont/go-sigma-rule-engine) by Markus Kont) to an executable so that I can upload it to AWS Lambda [(which is Amazon Linux 2 under the hood I believe, according to this post.)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html)  and include/execute it via a Python Lambda function that issues shell/os commands to the rule engine program.

**Problem:** This program relies on many dependencies and for it to work with as few issues as possible I would like to statically link the program and compile, before uploading to AWS Lambda, so that all necessary dependencies are included within the executable itself.

**Question:** How do I statically link then compile a program in Go such that I target the AWS Lambda OS?

Comment: So if I did `go build .` on the program's source code directory, the resultant executable would be completely standalone?

If so, why do guides like this exist: https://oddcode.daveamit.com/2018/08/16/statically-compile-golang-binary/

Are they just outdated?

Comment: Go has always output a statically linked binary AFAIK that includes all your modules written in Go. However, the program still depends on C libraries which are dynamically linked. This shouldn't be a problem in most cases (as the C libraries Go depends on are included in target OS) unless you're using your own C libraries through CGO. In the link you're referring to, the author is talking about statically linking those C libraries as well.

Comment: So what command would I use to target the Amazon Linux 2 OS and build the executable?

Comment: Assuming that your application does not have third party cgo dependencies, the Go executable should run with the default packages on Amazon Linux 2 OS.  Use this command: `GOOS=linux go build`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via `GOOS=linux go build .`

Go builds statically linked executables by default so as long as the correct OS is targeted, you will get a binary that runs fine on AWS Lambda without having to include any specific libraries in the deployment package.